# Tensorflow accuracy evaluation gives different results when measuring each class separately

Tags: tensorflow, average, conv-neural-network, evaluation

I'm evaluating results of my neural network model in tensorflow (recognizing CIFAR10 images).
After each epoch I'm printing accuracy on test set like this (x are images and y are true labels):

```
predict = tf.equal(tf.argmax(layer_model, 1), tf.argmax(y, 1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(predict, "float"))

print("Accuracy: ", accuracy.eval({ x: test_images, y: test_labels)
```

But then, I'm trying to get separate accuracy results for each class of images like that:

```
# test_labels look like: [0,1,0,...,0], [0,0,0,1,...,0], ...
labels_classes = np.argwhere(test_labels == 1)

chosen_class = np.argwhere(labels_classes[:,1] == j)
chosen_class = chosen_class.reshape(chosen.shape[0])
class_images = test_images[chosen]
class_labels = test_labels[chosen]
accuracy.eval({x: class_images, y: class_labels)
```

This second way of printing accuracy gives me about 10% worse results on average. Could anyone tell me what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

You may use `tf.metrics.mean_per_class_accuracy(labels,predictions,num_classes)`

Which labels are your ground truth labels and predictions are your predictions results. the shape of labels and predictions should be [batch size] and type int32 or int64.